# MySQL find_in_set selecting not working

Tags: mysql, select, find-in-set

I'm trying to do the following:

- Select from current year: Working
- Select where user_id **is in** comma seperated list 'users': Works
- Select where user_id **is NOT in** comma seperated list 'accepted' **OR** 'rejected': Not working

But for some reason I don't get the results I want. See my following code:

```
SELECT   *, MONTH(datetime) AS month
FROM     $table_name
WHERE    YEAR(datetime) = $current_year
AND      find_in_set('%$user_id%', users)
AND NOT  find_in_set('%$user_id%', accepted) OR NOT find_in_set('%$user_id%', rejected)
ORDER BY datetime
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `NOT` clause condition in parenthesis.

```
WHERE    YEAR(datetime) = $current_year
AND      find_in_set('%$user_id%', users)
AND (    NOT find_in_set('%$user_id%', accepted) 
      OR NOT find_in_set('%$user_id%', rejected) )
```